# Is there a way to display an image if the requested image is not in my assets?

Tags: dart, flutter

the title might be a bit confusing but i'll try to explain it better with an example.
I am using the widget

```
Image.asset(
            'assets/images/${object.name}.jpg',
          ),
```

but i want to show a default image (from assets or network) if the selected one is not available.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **errorBuilder** function to return another widget if the asset loading fails.

```
Widget createImage(String iconName) {
  return Image.asset('assets/icons/${iconName}.png',
      errorBuilder: (context, object, stacktrace) =>
          Image.asset('assets/icons/default.png'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a placeholder you could use the following package [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image).

```
CachedNetworkImage(
       imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
       placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
       errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Comment: He wants to load an image from the asset bundle not from the network